# Cloning Production org is possible?

Tags: configuration

By the end of the year, we have 40 Orgs to deploy for 40 entities of a big company. (it's an architecture choice that has been validated).

The admin has already configured 3 orgs and would like to industrialize the configuration of the next 37 ones. He does not want to go manually to the setup screens to do things like: 
  - define the paswword strategy
  - define the session parameters
  - define Salesforce1 parameters, etc...

In my understanding, it is not possible to use change sets to deploy these configuration settings to other orgs.

The solution would be to define a master (a Production Org already configured but without functional data) and clone it as many times as needed to create the rest of the organisation.

Do you think it is possible ?

Comment: Someone also talked me about Trialforce. It targets the ISVs but could resolve my issue. Someone already tested it ?

Answer (score 5):

You're correct, most of those settings aren't available through the normal Metadata APIs. I can think of two simple solutions to this problem.

First, ask salesforce if they'll do it for you. They (used to) have a special process called DOT cloning, which basically took all the configuration of an org and dropped it into a new org. I don't know if they still have this feature, or if they'll do it for you, but it doesn't hurt to ask.

Second, you might consider just recording a macro. I'd consider using [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/). Here's how it works: fire up your browser, tell Selenium to start recording, click on the various things you want to configure, stop recording, then log in to each new org and click play (precise details may vary). It wouldn't be as fast as a DOT clone, but it sure beats clicking all those links yourself. Make sure that each org comes from the same template and starting point when you use Selenium, as if it gets confused, you'll just have wasted time.

Comment: And make sure that the macro can log in to every org with the proper creds. :-)

Comment: @SebastianKessel I usually just log in first before recording the macro, and make sure I'm logged in before I play it back. But that's a good point. Macros are often fragile, and Selenium used to give me fits when I tried to set up visual unit testing for our pages.

Comment: Thank's . I will contact Salesforce first. I saw the DOT process in another blog and it seems it was no more used.